# Web3: call the solidity function with the address can't return the expected outcome! (everyone can help?)

Tags: web3js, truffle, addresses

solidity code:

```
address public administrator;

constructor() public {
    administrator = msg.sender;  
}

function isAdministrator(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
    return _address == administrator;
}
```

web3 code

[image]

The expected outcome is return true but the con.log returns false.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

In the truffle console call the function by input the admin address will return true, in web3 it returns false whatever input the admin address or other address it still returns false! I think the problem is about the web3 code but I don't which part was wrong! The address part in web3 needs to convert?

I am using the truffle pet-shop box to do my project! 
everyone can help me?

Truffle v5.1.22 (core: 5.1.22)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.3
Web3.js v1.2.1

Comment: This is a very-low quality question, with all those screenshots. How is one supposed to refer to your code and/or printout when they cannot copy-paste from it into their answer??? Also, what does "con.log returns false" even mean??? The `console.log` (yes - please don't use "shortcuts" in your description) doesn't return anything. It prints. And your printout isn't of `true` or `false`, it's of an object! I'll answer it nevertheless, but please edit and fix all of the above, and try to keep your future questions clearer. Add `.call()` after `electionInstance.isAdministrator(address)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! For the console log return false that means this input address that is not admin address.  web3 code is calling the isadministrator function from the solidity code that only will return a bool. I find out the problem by myself and the .call() is Unsuitable for my situation.

Comment: Please tell me how u fixed this problem, it's really annoying